# How to check if a multiple user-inputs are NOT empty

Tags: php, string, function

I tried to build a function that can check a set of strings for me and find out whether its empty strings ("") or not, So after playing around for sometime, I created this one:

```
function blank() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $result;
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        if ($arg == "") {
            $result = TRUE;
            continue;
        } else {
            $result = FALSE;
            return $result;
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return $result;
}

$name = "Hamed";
$email = "";

if (!blank($name, $email)){
    $msg = "Not blank";
} else {
    $msg = "It's blank!";
}
echo $msg;
```

It worked PERFECTLY!
But now the problem is I didn't understand the detailed steps of how it worked.
How each line works and how the keyword continue and the return-ed results output in the different scoops of the code.
Thanks

Edit: BTW empty() and isset() will not work in this case, because once i click the submit button, the results of both isset() and !empty() = TRUE .

Comment: And simply use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for checking if a string (or any var) is blank.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, as i said I'm a beginner, So i'm trying to use all my knowledge to do something and understand how it works.

Comment: Your code is wrong i will answer with a correct one

Comment: For a slightly steeper learning curve consider `function blank() {
 $args = func_get_args();
 return empty( array_filter($args, 'strlen') );
}` ;-) see also: http://docs.php.net/array_filter

Comment: I know that i can use empty() but i have multiple vars, empty() will only accept one variable.

Comment: empty() in this case works on an array; the one returned by array_filter. Your profile says "Web Designer & Developer", would it help if provided a javascript equivalent?

Comment: Thank you for your help @VolkerK , Sorry I didn't get your point in this "Your profile says ..."

Comment: I just wanted to know if it would help you if I provided a javascript equivalent for both your and my implementation. Given that your profile says that you're a web designer and developer I thought you might know your way around javascript.

Comment: @Volkerk Yes i'm still beginner also in JS, but i kind of hold it for sometime now, so i can focus on backend (php) and then i'll go back to JS again.
Thank you again for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do this in multiple iterations:
First let's remove the obviously superfluous code

```
<?php
function blank() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    // $result; - superfluous, that's a no-op
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        if ($arg == "") {
            $result = TRUE;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            $result = FALSE;
            return $result;
        }
        /* code execution will never reach this point
        because the if-branch jumps right back to the loop header
        and the else-branch exists the function completely
        therefore:
        */
        // return $result; -superfluous, 
    }
    return $result;
}
```

second iteration: remove the little bit less obviously superfluous code

```
function blank() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        if ($arg == "") {
            $result = TRUE;
            // no need for "continue" here; there's nothing else in the loop (anymore)
            // than the if-else branch
            //continue;
        }
        else {
            // no need to assign the return value to any variable here
            // $result = FALSE;
            // return $result;
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

So, all that's left is

```
function blank() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        if ($arg == "") {
            $result = TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

it loops through the arguments array and executes the if-branch again and again, setting again and again $result=TRUE - until the else-branch is executed *once*, which just returns FALSE.
In case the else-branch is never executed for the whole array, it returns $result, which can only be TRUE (set by the if-branch) or undefined (when there was no element in the array $args and hence neither the if- nor the else-branch has been executed).

Therefore you can even simplifiy this further:

```
function blank() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        if ($arg != "") {
            // if there is one non-blank element in the arguments -> return false
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    // there was no non-blank element in the arguments array ->
    return true;
}
```

(I leave the edge-case(s) to you...., e.g. calling blank() with no argument at all)

edit: I left the `$args=func_get_args()` line in there (instead of `foreach(func_get_args()....` because the new(er) [variable-length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) syntax would look like

```
function blank(...$args) {
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        if ($arg != "") {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The final results of both my code and your code are almost the same However there might be a slightly deference in how each of the functions are performing the results.
The results that i was need is to make sure that all of the variables are not empty, so if (any) of them is empty the function should return true.
So i tested my code and it worked in all the situations, but your code still shorter and simpler and a little tricky for beginners like myself.

Comment: "are almost the same" - Can you provide an example where the two versions have differing results?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the same code with some comments added to clarify things

```
function blank() {
    //put all arguments passed to function in $args array (allows any number of args)
    $args = func_get_args(); 
    $result; //initialize $result (not needed)
    foreach ($args as $arg) { //Loop through $args
        if ($arg == "") { 
            $result = TRUE;
            continue; //Do not process any more line in this loop (continue to next item)
        } else {
            //if the arg is not empty return False
            $result = FALSE;
            return $result; 
        }
        //This will never be reached
        return $result; 
    }
    //if all arguments were empty we will reach this point
    //At that point $result will be True, so return True;
    return $result;
}
```

Here is an optimization that maybe makes it easier to understand what the function does:

```
function blank() {
    //put all arguments passed to function in $args array (allows any number of args)
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $arg) { //Loop through $args
        if ( ! emtpy($arg) ) { 
           //Return False if we ever find a non empty argument
           return False
        }
    }
    //if all arguments were empty we will reach this point
    //At that point $result will be True, so return True;
    return True;
}
```

Of course there are many other ways to rewrite this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for you, but in fact it isnt.
If it was working it would have outputed the result for each $name and $email.
You had 3 returns in your function, so the function stops at this line and return only result for first argument.
I will not go further in my explaination, but i suggest you to keep learning php's basics.
Read carefully my code below, and compare with yours, and try to understand what's wrong with yours.
We all learn from our mistakes :)
Good luck

Here is your code rewrited:

```
<?php
function blank(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    $result = array();
    foreach ($args as $key) {
        if ($key == "") {
            $result[] = array("$key", "It's blank");
        }
        else{
            $result[] = array("$key", "Not Blank");
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$name = "Hamed";
$email = "";

$data = blank($name, $email);

print_r($data);
?>
```

Output :

```
    Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [0] => Hamed [1] => Not Blank ),
        [1] => Array ( [0] =>  [1] => It's blank ) 
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Actually i posted this question here to get a more "further explanation" here..
So if you don't mind please explain in details what's wrong in my code and how it should be.
BTW I didn't want to output the name or the email, i only wanted to check if they were empty or not.

Comment: I will explain in details.. wait some moments